# Get the Sip Incoming call id

Tags: android

I want to know how can i get the incoming call id when the sip incoming call is received.I have use the Telephony and Phone manager but in both the cases the state i got the null because i am not using the phone's dial pad.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a BroadcastReceiver to receive incoming calls, you have to use `SipManager.getCallId(incomingCallIntent)` inside your 'onReceive()' method.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this and not found any answer, the sample app (sipDemo) do not handle incoming call too. Fortunately I found the answer:

`mSipManager.getSessionFor(intent).getPeerProfile().getUserName()`

Good luck ;)